# Sub-array, variable number of values in the array, and retrieval of repetitions

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want get data from several APIs:

```
var apis = ['http://api1.com/get', 'http://api13.com/get', 'http://api11.com/get', 'http://api11.com/get', 'http://api2.com/get'];
```

or

```
var apis = ['http://api1.com/get', 'http://api5.com/get'];
```

Each api return me object, for example:

```
{
   title: example,
   cities: {{'letter' : 'A', 'name': 'Mexico'}, {'letter' : 'B', 'name' : 'New York'}, {'letter': 'C', 'name': 'London'}}
}
```

The city always has the same letter.

```
apis.forEach(function(api) {
    //get operations...
    var cities = api.cities;
});
```

Here I should assign data to the arrays so that I can compare them later, but I do not know how to do it.

In PHP I can:

```
$array = [];
foreach ($apis as $i => $api) {
    //get operations...
    foreach ($cities as $city) {
       $array[$i][] = $city['letter'];
    }
}

$repetitions = call_user_func_array("array_intersect", $array);
```

How can I do it in JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

Declare an empty array outside the forEach loop like `var arr = [];`
Then whenever you want to add an element to the array, use
`arr.push(city['letter']);`

Comment: But then the data from all the tables will land in one and I will not be able to see if they repeat.